# erro no balanceamento com SMOTE

Tags: r, dataset

Olá, tenho um dataset um pouco desbalanceado e queria fazer uns teste com smote, mas estou recebendo um erro:

```
library(DMwR)
```

> ```
> treinoSmote <- SMOTE(TARGET ~ .,m,k=5, perc.over = 100, perc.under = 200)
> Error in factor(newCases[, a], levels = 1:nlevels(data[, a]), labels = levels(data[,  : 
> invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 2
> ```

o meu TARGET já é um factor, deixei ele com valores 1 e 0, com S e N (SIM e NÃO) etc, sempre da esse erro.

meu dataset é composto por features integer, factor e numeric. São umas 20 no momento.

As únicas coisas que eu vejo na internet falam que deve ser factor e tals, mas já está!

Fiz o teste que tem na documentação do próprio SMOTE com o dataset iris e ele funciona normal. Verifiquei o tipo da feature e está como factor também. Não entendo porque está dando esse erro.

```
data(iris)
data <- iris[,c(1,2,5)]
data$Species <- factor(ifelse(data$Species == "setosa", "rare", "common"))
table(data$Species)
common   rare 
100     50 

newData <- SMOTE(Species ~ ., data, perc.over = 600, perc.under = 100)
table(newData$Species)
common   rare 
300    350
```

Comment: Seria interessante você disponibilizar seu banco de dados (ou uma parte dele) para reproduzirmos da mesma forma. Utilize o comando `dput`

Comment: assim serve?  https://anotepad.com/notes/ind9p6 rsrs não achei lugar pra anexar ou algo assim

Comment: Convém também dizer qual o pacote usado, uma vez que a função `SMOTE` não é uma função R base. Nestes casos comece *sempre* a pergunta com o carregamento do pacote, `library(DMwR)`.

Comment: desculpe, eu não tinha visto que não tinha colocado, já editei lá

Comment: pqp achei o erro. Tinha uma feature que nao tinha convertido corretamente. Desculpe o transtorno. a F8 devia ser factor e estava character

Answer (score 1):

eu havia deixado uma feature com o tipo character, não havia convertido para factor. Não era na feature target, era no meio.

Apenas usei o as.factor e consegui rodar normalmente

```
m$F8 <- as.factor(m$F8)
```